# How can I create multiple server streams for a single user in gatling grpc load scripts

Tags: gatling

**What do I want to achieve?**

For each user, I want to create multiple server streams and for each stream I want to ensure the response received has a certain state.

**What behaviour am I seeing?**

The user is able to successfully create the first stream but runs into the following error when creating subsequent streams.

`Unable to create a new server stream with name stream1: already exists 12:07:56.809 [gatling-1-1] ERROR c.g.p.g.g.a.ServerStreamStartAction - 'serverStreamStart-2' failed to execute: Unable to create a new server stream with name stream1: already exists`

**What have I tried?**
See below for an excerpt of what my code looks like

```
class StreamingSimulation {

  private final val sc = scenario("simulation-lt-scenario")
      .feed(
        feederFor("payload", requestHelper.getStreamingRequest()
      )
      .exec(
          grpc("action request").serverStream("stream1")
              .start(GrpcService.getMyStreamingMethod)($("payload"))
              .check(extract { r: MyResponse => Option(r.someState) } is STATE_A))
      )

  setUp(
    scn.inject(rampUsers(1))
      . throttle(
        reachRPS(throttleRPS) in (60 seconds)
        holdFor(300 seconds)
      )
      .maxDuration(300 seconds)
      .protocols(grpc(configureChannel(config)))
  )
}
```

Looks like a user is not supposed to create more than 1 stream using this setup. I am wondering if there is an alternative approach I can take that will allow me to reach my desired behaviour?

Comment: You can create a stream with a different name.

Answer (score 0):

Here-- grpc("action request").serverStream("stream1")     you could try to append the timestamp to the serverstream name so that it gets a new stream name each time as below--grpc("action request").serverStream("stream1_" + timestamp)

We encountered the same issue and had tried this option but we are still stuck at this point. You may try this suggestion and see if this resolves it for you or if its already resolved for you via some other means let us know.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this behavior when using with Loop (forever, during, repeat), avoid using these if you can.

Also ***throttle*** is not compatible with stream yet, only ***UNARY*** (at least for now), you may experience some timeout prematurely.

Hope this help !