# How to properly close a gRPC stream in a loop for Gatling

Tags: scala, grpc, gatling

I am handling a throttle with 1 QPS in Gatling for 1 minute run set up as this pseudo code:

```
Scenario_set_up
   inject (1 user) for (1 minute)
   throttle (reach 1 rps in 1 second) holdFor (1 minutes)
maxDuration is 1 minute
```

and for the workflow, I have 2 gRPC API, one is server Stream, the other one is a bidiStream, defined as below, using forever loop

```
Scenario_set_up
   tryAgainIfFail(3)
   loopWorkflow_until_duration_reach_1_minute{
       exec(ServerStream_API)
       exec(bidiStream_API)
   }
```

By executing this setup scenario, I will complete first loop without any issue, for the second loop, on the same User, I will get this error log

```
serverStream_API failed to execute: Unable to create a new server stream with name "ServerStream": already exists
```

My guessing is that the stream could not close connection properly, so it keeps connecting, thus blocking next loop from reusing it. How do I bypass this blocking ?

Edit: I saw in bidiStream there is a ***complete*** method which cut-out peacefully, maybe a ***complete*** in this case help too ?

Much Appreciate any help.

================================================================

Refer to this question's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721185/how-can-i-create-multiple-server-streams-for-a-single-user-in-gatling-grpc-load) (identical)